# How to use other python modules with jep?

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea, jep

I've set up a jep project within IntelliJ-IDEA, and keep getting this error when I run my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" jep.JepException: <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>: No module named 'spacy'
at src/main/python\nlq_wrapper.<module>(nlq_wrapper.py:2)
at <string>.<module>(<string>:1)
at jep.Jep.exec(Native Method)
at jep.Jep.exec(Jep.java:478)
at com.siemens.nlqwrapper.NLQWrapper.load(NLQWrapper.java:37)
at com.siemens.nlqwrapper.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Even though spacy is included in my interpreter SDK packages. [image]

Another weird thing is that the Python terminal within IntelliJ-IDEA can find and use spacy. [image]

But when I try and run the program from the terminal or from my system's CLI, it can't find the modules and I get the same error. [image]

Is there some extra configuration for jep that I need to do to be able to use other python modules with it? or is jep just not compatible with other modules?

**EDIT**

For further clarification here are the run configurations for Java and Python.

Java run configuration:[image]

Python run configuration:[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the run configuration you use (Run | Edit Configurations...)?

Comment: @SergeyK. thanks for clarifying; I've updated my questions to include my run configurations. Should I also add my project structure?

Comment: Try running it from the system CLI with the same venv activated. What's the result?

Comment: @SergeyK. I've done that and it has the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it thru this code you call before JEP interpreter:

```
 PyConfig pyConfig = new PyConfig();
  pyConfig.setPythonHome("/home/user/[NEW_PYTHON_HOME]/");
  try {
    MainInterpreter.setInitParams(pyConfig);
  } catch (JepException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Ali